# How to open multiple windows for different notebooks in Jupyter Lab at start up?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

So basically, I've been trying to find a way to automatically have multiple windows opened, each with its own notebook files (say, Untitled.ipynb & Untitled1.ipynb), at the startup time of JupyterLab in browser.
From what I've learned, this would mean that separate ipykernels are running for each window.

Is it possible to do this with NO manual mouse clicking or dragging?

My expected outcome is similar to what is done in below link, only wanting it done already at the first display at startup :
https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*tztJflyC75wwuS5rZCi_4g.gif